# Inicializar un array de arrays asociativos en PHP

Tags: php, array

Sé que para declarar un array se hace de la siguiente forma:

```
public $hijo = array();
// ó
public $hijo[];
```

y para un array asociativo:

```
 public $hijo = array (
    'idPregunta' => '',
    'codigo' => '',
    'pregunta' => ''
);
```

Ahora, intento declarar un **array de arrays asociativos** de la siguiente forma:

```
public $hijo[] = array (
    'idPregunta' => '',
    'codigo' => '',
    'pregunta' => ''
);
```

pero me marca el siguiente error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de hacer esto?

Comment: ya probaste con: `$hijo = array (
    'idPregunta' => '',...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hacen falta los [] antes del contenido. Puedes declararlo de dos maneras:

**A. Con el constructor array()**

```
public $hijo = 
  array (
    'idPregunta' => '1',
    'codigo' => '01',
    'pregunta' => '¿por qué puso ud []'
   );
```

Según el Manual de PHP:

> Un array puede ser creado con el constructor del lenguaje array(). Éste toma cualquier número de parejas clave => valor como argumentos.
>
> ```
> array(
>         clave  => valor,
>         clave2 => valor2,
>         clave3 => valor3,
>         ...
> )
> ```
>
> La coma después del último elemento del array es opcional, pudiéndose omitir. Esto normalmente se hace para arrays de una única línea, es decir, es preferible array(1, 2) que array(1, 2, ). Por otra parte, para arrays multilínea, la coma final se usa frecuentemente, ya que permite una adición más sencilla de nuevos elementos al final.
>
> <sub>[Documentación sobre `array` en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php)</sub>

A partir de PHP 5.4 también se puede usar la sintaxis de array corta, la cual permite reemplazar `array()` con `[]`.

**B. A partir de PHP 5.4 : usando `[ ]` perooo...**

encerrando el contenido del array entre corchetes, no colocando corchetes después del nombre de la variable:

```
// a partir de PHP 5.4
$array = 
  [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
  ];
```

**C. Array multidimensional**

Se declara de la misma manera:

```
$array = 
    array(
          "foo" => "bar",
          42    => 24,
          "multi" => array(
                            "dimensional" => 
                               array(
                                      "array" => "foo"
                                     )
                           )
          );
```

Comment: entonces ¿en que momento se diferencian los arrays de la variables simples? Me queda esa duda. ¿Cuando itero la variable poniendole [] ahí es donde empieza a ser array?

Comment: He editado la respuesta para que quede más claro. Es array porque así lo has declarado, sea usando el constructor array (), sea colocando entre [] el **contenido** de lo que declaras.

Comment: si, pero así cómo lo planteas es un array, no un array de arrays. Esos es lo que intento preguntar pero no sé si no me explico correctamente

Comment: Será un array de arrays cuando incluyas otros arrays dentro de tu array. Eso depende del contenido que haya dentro, no de la forma en que lo declares. No sé si me explico.

Comment: ok. ahora queda claro ese punto. ¿Podrias modificar tu pregunta aclarando ese punto para que marque la respuesta como aceptada?

Comment: He añadido un punto C. a la respuesta con un ejemplo de array multidmensional, o sea un array de arrays o un array que tiene más arrays dentro.

Comment: Preguntabas: _¿Cuando itero la variable poniendole [] ahí es donde empieza a ser array?_ Como ya queda claro, es un array desde que lo creas, de modo que para iterar no tienes que ponerle nada a la variable, ya PHP sabe que es un array. Puedes iterar directamente. Ejemplo: `$colors = array('rojo', 'azul', 'verde', 'amarillo'); foreach ($colors as $color) { echo "¿Le gusta el $color?\n";}`

Answer (score 1):

[`public`](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php) es para declarar la visibilidad de una propiedad o método a los miembros de un clase.

```
$hijo = []; // iniciar array

$hijo[] = [
    'idPregunta' => '',
    'codigo' => '',
    'pregunta' => ''
];

print_r($hijo);
```

[Ver ejemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7e21560a15926481a886c510123581c114ec0c9c)

[A partir de PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php) también se puede usar la sintaxis de array corta, la cual reemplaza `array()` con `[]`.

Comment: si. olvide aclarar que esta variable es un atributo de una clase.

Comment: @ReneLimon - La verdad no entiendo ahora muy bien tu pregunta... Mira [este](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ac438ce8dc0b9dbf09ffaa4d14213fc61a2f7ea2) ejemplo... si le pones los `[]` a la declaración te sale el mismo error que tienes ahora.. y es simplemente un error de sintaxis... no se si eso te soluciona tu duda...

Comment: la respuesta de @acedano era correcta, no es necesario poner los corchetes para declarar un array de arrays

Comment: @ReneLimon - No que no sea necesario... es un error de sintaxis...