# Notice: Undefined offset

Tags: php

Intenté inicializar o declarar la variable `$current_link = [];` dado a la segunda respuesta de esta pregunta [Inicializar un array de arrays asociativos en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50610/inicializar-un-array-de-arrays-asociativos-en-php) pero sigue mostrando el error en esta línea `if ($current_link[1]) {`

```
#$current_link = [];
$current_link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$current_link = explode('publishers=', $current_link);

if ($current_link[1]) {
    if (strpos($current_link[1], '?')) {
        $publishers = substr($current_link[1], 0, strpos($current_link[1], '?'));
    }
    if (strpos($current_link[1], '&')) {
        $publishers = substr($current_link[1], 0, strpos($current_link[1], '&'));
    }
    if (strpos($current_link[1], '/')) {
        $publishers = substr($current_link[1], 0, strpos($current_link[1], '/'));
    }
} else {
    $publishers = 'Orgánico';
}
echo $publishers;
```

Usando `print_r($current_link);` obtengo lo siguiente:

```
Array ( [0] => http://example.com/demo.php?publishers1=11DATg/NL49tr3pMqO2Erj2OYJnRuRXHaCYmKCF3JSEbh3iMRBDRPiTN?? )
```

Cuando si existe coincidencia en la URL con el parámetro `publishers` no muestra error, ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP no interpreta `falsy` como lo hace Javascript o Python. [¿Qué es un falsy?](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Incluye funciones para evaluar si lo que estás intentando evaluar tiene una sintaxis conocida.

Puedes usar `empty()` o `is_null()` te dejo las referencias de cómo usarlos, para ejemplos prácticos, te corrijo tu código

```
if ( !empty( $current_link[1] ) ) {
 // Your stuff
}
```

[¿Cómo usar empty()?](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php)

[¿Cómo usar is_null()?](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-null.php)

Answer (score 1):

el problema es que intentas acceder a un indice de $current_link que no existe, intenta usando isset para válidar que el indice exista, tu código quedaría algo así:

```
#$current_link = [];
$current_link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$current_link = explode('publishers=', $current_link);

if (isset($current_link[1])) {
    if (strpos($current_link[1], '?')) {
        $publishers = substr($current_link[1], 0, strpos($current_link[1], '?'));
    }
    if (strpos($current_link[1], '&')) {
        $publishers = substr($current_link[1], 0, strpos($current_link[1], '&'));
    }
    if (strpos($current_link[1], '/')) {
        $publishers = substr($current_link[1], 0, strpos($current_link[1], '/'));
    }
} else {
    $publishers = 'Orgánico';
}
echo $publishers;
```

Espero sea útil, saludos.

Comment: con `isset()` evaluaría un true, ya que esta verifica que la variable esté inicializada, independientemente del valor que esta contenga.

Comment: No, no lo evalúa true.. Si el indice indicado no existe lo evalua false, si le paso únicamente la variable, si lo evalua true.

Comment: Tienes razón, sin embargo evalúa null, esta función no resolvería el problema, por que el OP de la undefined (null). Es la única excepción de isset(). Está en la documentación

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob Hola probé con `isset()` el error ya no se muestra voy a probar con `!empty`

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob También funciona `!empty` ambas funciones funciona.

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob, no, no evalúa null, porque la variable no esta definida, no es nula, la excepción no aplica.

Answer (score 0):

comprueba que exista el indice primero con la función **isset**

```
<?php
$current_link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$current_link = explode('publishers=', $current_link);

if (isset($current_link[1])) {
    if (strpos($current_link[1], '?')) {
        $publishers = substr($current_link[1], 0, strpos($current_link[1], '?'));
    }
    if (strpos($current_link[1], '&')) {
        $publishers = substr($current_link[1], 0, strpos($current_link[1], '&'));
    }
    if (strpos($current_link[1], '/')) {
        $publishers = substr($current_link[1], 0, strpos($current_link[1], '/'));
    }
} else {
    $publishers = 'Orgánico';
}
echo $publishers;
```